# create a widget using php for use on external sites

Tags: php, iframe, widget

I thought it would be a great idea to let our associated dealers have the opportunity to have this on their own site as a widget. https://www.autopower.no/ ("Effektoversikt" to the right).
The "effektoversikt" fetches data from our MySQL database. Once the user finds their car and clicks "søk!" (search) they should be redirected to our page...

I'm thinking using `iframe`- or `script`-tags is the solution?
could someone point me in the right direction on where to start?

Answer (score 0):

this could be a div element fed by a ajax request. The ajax request returns html snippet as search form, and when you submit, result is sent by website that generated the ajax request (so it looks like a redirect for the end user).

[edit]

- Source website has an url that creates a HTML snippet as <form>...</form>. Say, not an HTML page, only the form.
- target website uses, for example, [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to fetch the form via an Ajax request and set the html  snippet into a div in target's website. As the form target is on the source website, a submit on the form automatically forward to that source site.

So create first a script/whatever that exposes the HTML snippet, then try to insert it into another page. You can experiment insertion part on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: not really sure how to accomplish this. If you have any link to some article or tutorial I could study upon; Please let me know...

Comment: This thread may help you : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/prototype-scriptaculous/1QqgH0EHahg